# Duplicate Partitions Causing Issues?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted

I've observed an unusual event in the drives menu and after executing `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,uuid` in terminal. I get this output after executing the command:

[image: Multiple Disks]

There are multiple swap partitions for some reason. Not just that, but there are also multiple 150G disks, where I only have one 150G disk. I've only seen 1 swap partition on other people's computers that executed that command. I should also not that this is a default installation, with no messing around with partitions, although this did come from a Windows system originally. Although, I did wipe the entire disk upon Ubuntu installation. This is also mirrored in the `disks` utility, when viewing it from a bootable USB with 16.04.02 on it.

[image: Disk 0]

And the other disk:

[image: Disk 1]

This also may be the cause of a `gparted` error message when I try to edit the partitions from the bootable USB:

[image: Gparted Error Message]

Is there any way that I can only get 1 disk to show on these lists? I only have 1 integrated 150GB hard drive, and I think that this is causing issues with the rest of the system.

Comment: I think you have two physical drives in a RAID configuration. And with RAID, gparted does not work. You have to use RAID tools. The error on 2048 is usually from the flash drive/live installer. Usually not an issue. You show two physical disks in left panel. You probably have BIOS RAID or "FakeRAID" https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto And if RAID 0, if one drive fails then you lose all data on both drives. If RAID 1, the one is mirror of other. But RAID is not backup. You must be doing backups.

Comment: @oldfred So this isn't necessarily an issue? If I do a standard instalation wiping the disk, will this cause any problems like a buggy startup after suspending? I think it's suspicious that there are multiple swap partitions, and I'm having issues coming back from suspend. It feels like something weird is going on with the swap partition.

Comment: Do you want RAID? Is it BIOS RAID or is your hard drive(s) set for RAID, not AHCI nor IDE. If you have good backups, you can break the RAID and have two 160GB drives. IF RAID 0 that will destroy all data on drive as half is one one drive and half on other drive in alternating stripes. RAID 0 is just for speed. Now most use SSD for speed. It also looks like you have encryption. Is that what you want also? I do not know RAID, LVM nor encryption.

Comment: Can you open the computer and look? The drives have different serial numbers.